# Datomic shell implementation

Tags: shell, clojure, datomic

I start the datomic shell using the following

```
bin/shell
```

The syntax reminds me a little of beanshell (no pun intended). Does anybody know what the shell is implemented in?

Comment: http://docs.datomic.com/shell.html - it's based on beanshell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Datomic docs say it is "based on beanshell" and links to http://beanshell.org/.  So it looks like it is based on the original bsh, not beanshell2 (http://code.google.com/p/beanshell2/).

Datomic doc reference: http://docs.datomic.com/shell.html